# MultiThreading in asp.net issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis

I have an application hosted on my server. this application sends emails to list of users. lets say the list have 10000 users. i divide the list into three parts and assign each to a seperate thread to send emails. The issue is when i the application in visual studio and run the application, it sends the emails to all the 3 list i have created, but when i browse the application remotely on my local pc. the emails is not sending. 
The code is inside a webservice i have created to send emails.Here is my code:

```
    ArrayList thList1 = new ArrayList(); 
    ArrayList thList2 = new ArrayList(); 
    ArrayList thList3 = new ArrayList(); 
    ArrayList thListId1 = new ArrayList(); 
    ArrayList thListId2 = new ArrayList(); 
    ArrayList thListId3 = new ArrayList(); 
    int countList = arlistuid.Count / 3; 
    int count; 
    for (count = 0; count < arlistuid.Count; count++) 
    { 
    if (count < countList)
    { 
       thList1.Add(arlistuid[count]); 
       thListId1.Add(arlistid[count]); 
    } 
    else if (count >= countList && (count < countList + countList)) 
    { 
       thList2.Add(arlistuid[count]); 
       thListId2.Add(arlistid[count]); 
    }
    else 
    { 
        thList3.Add(arlistuid[count]); 
        thListId3.Add(arlistid[count]); 
    }

   if (thList1.Count > 0)
   {
       object thdargs = new object[2] { thList1, thListId1 };
       Thread thd1 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(SplitListEmail));
       thd1.IsBackground = true;
       thd1.Name = "Thread1";
       thd1.Start(thdargs);
   }
   if (thList2.Count > 0)
   {
       object thd2args = new object[2] { thList2, thListId2 };
       Thread thd2 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(SplitListEmail));
       thd2.IsBackground = true;
       thd2.Name = "Thread2";
       thd2.Start(thd2args);
   }
   if (thList3.Count > 0)
   {        
       object thd3args = new object[2] { thList3, thListId3 };
       Thread thd3 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(SplitListEmail));
       thd3.IsBackground = true;
       thd3.Name = "Thread3";
       thd3.Start(thd3args);
   }
```

Can anybody help me what is the issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: looks fine. what's in SplitListEmail?

Comment: It's quite possible that SplitListEmail is your problem.

Comment: Depending on how you are running it locally (i.e. debugging from within Visual Studio) then I'd also think about authentication. If you run locally, you'll be running as you. If you hit the website remotely, you'll be running as whatever user IIS is configured to run as, and if this user doesn't have permission to access your webservice, for example, then it wont work. Check the windows event log for any errors.